# EFS mounts on ECS Fargate container platform on AWS and confirming it works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

I think I can mount a new EFS volume on my container because it gives me no errors. How do I verify if it is actually running or working and which container has it mounted. Does anyone know if there is a tool with the exception of building some library in my code to verify it.

Answer (score 0):

Two  possible option that you can try is

- [Mount EFS with EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/wt1-test.html) and verify the content (Manual way of verification)
- Add logic in the `startup.sh` the script in the container to verify the EFS integration (Automated)

suppose the mount point is

```
 "mountPoints": [
                {"containerPath": "/server",
                    "sourceVolume": "efs-server-AP"
                }
            ]
```

in a startup script, you can something like

```
# if this is the first time the server starts the config file is populated
mkdir -p /server
if [ ! -f /server/config.json ]; then 
echo "running first time"
echo ""running first time" > /server/config.json;
# generate some random file
echo $(date) > "$(date).txt"
else
echo "EFS working fine; list of file exist"
ls /server
fi
```

you can look into more details [developers-guide-to-using-amazon-efs-with-amazon-ecs-and-aws-fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/developers-guide-to-using-amazon-efs-with-amazon-ecs-and-aws-fargate-part-3/)